# meaning of "à la Weber"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of: à la Weber
in this phrase
"Democracy has become, à la Weber, synonymous with
equal treatment by bureaucracy"

Comment: It means "in the style of Weber", "as Weber described". For more information, I suggest you look up Weber on Google (Max Weber is the guy you probably want).

Comment: Related: *[Does the casual use of “a la ___” in English preserve the French meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10390)*

Answer (score 2):

It's taken from French, but generally means "like" or "in the style of". So you could say someone driving quickly was "driving à la Senna", or a crime novelist's description was "à la Le Carre" (which might be a bit of a mouthful!)

Comment: The double article in *à la Le Carré* is just so wrong (maybe not in English, but …).

Comment: I know, that's why I used it. ;)

Comment: @PeterShor It's what we'd use in French too. Articles that are part of a name are considered proper nouns, they don't change even when *de* or *à* is in front.

Comment: “à la …” is short for “à la mode de ….” So “à la Le Carré” means “à la mode de Le Carré”.

Comment: Very off-topic, but I know that if you go to Le Havre, in French you go "au Havre", not "à Le Havre".  Therefore, should "à la mode de Le Carré" be "à la mode du Carré"?